# Is there AMD Overdrive on Ubuntu?

Tags: ati, overclocking

Is there AMD Overdrive on Ubuntu? Because I want to install it if possible, but i seem to have the latest AMD drivers installed. Does anyone have an AMD Graphics card? If they do could you please tell me if there is a working overdrive section for Catalist control center? By the way, i have the ATI Radeon HD 4850 graphics card.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a open source project called AMDoverdriveCtrl on source forge

http://sourceforge.net/projects/amdovdrvctrl

Answer (score 0):

There is not. I have not really explored this, but there might be something in bios, depending.

Honestly, however, overclocking your graphics cards gives almost no performance boost.

If you're experiencing a slow desktop environment (lagging when moving windows, playing videos and the such), then I suggest that you go turn off vsync in compizconfig, as that's what's holding back the framerate.

Answer (score 0):

You no need additional package for the overclocking , Just Package Called aticonfig.

To Switch the Overdrive(TM) on, Just type aticonfig --od-enable, Then Do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line interface to the amdconfig utility.

The command for overclocking is as follows:

```
amdconfig --od-enabled
```

To get the valid clock range, and current closk speed

```
amdconfig --odgc
```

To set the top clock speed use the following command:

```
amdconfig --odsc [Corespeed],[Memoryspeed]
```

To set the currently set clocks to be used on normal X11 starts:

```
amdconfig --odcc
```

To set the system back to default run the following command then restart X:

```
amdconfig --od-disable
```

More advanced settings are available through undocumented commands or the new AMD Display Controller configuration library.

If your serious about tweaking your card I'd recommend the AMDoverdriveCtrl application recommended by another user.  However, you will need to rebuild it if you are using the latest version of Ubuntu due to library incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt get install radeon-profile
```

this will install a gtk based radeon/ati/amd GPU controller (fan speed, mem/cpu core freq etc)